# Timer after autolock

Tags: ios

Is there a way to get the timer in the Clock app to sound the alarm when the iPad has been autolocked?

For example if I have set the iPad to Autolock after 15 minutes and start a timer for 20 minutes, the alarm doesn't sound.

Comment: so you want the alarm to sound while iPad is locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets couriouser and couriouser.  If the autolock time is equal to the timer time, the alarm does not sound.  If I add a second to the timer, my iPad goes to sleep and then the alarm sounds.    Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Alarm to sound while iPad is locked.

Based on what you've described, I would first suggest force closing the Clock app: [Follow instructions from Apple here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330)

Then, restart your device.

Comment: @MarvinGardens it helps us if you check mark the answer so others can find it with same problem